# Finding the Union and Intersection of the indexed collection?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

For each natural number $n≥3$ let,

$A_n$ = $[\frac1n, 2+ \frac1n]$ and $\mathscr A\ =${$A_n :$$n≥3$}

So what I did first to solve this problem is I plug in natural numbers greater than or equal to 3.

$A_3$ = [$\frac13, \frac73$]

$A_4 = $ [$ \frac14, \frac94]$

$A_5 = $ [$ \frac15, \frac{11}{5}]$

Here is where I get stuck I know that the definition of union is
Let A be a family of sets. The union over A is $ $∪A$_{A∈ \mathscr A}$ = { $x: x ∈ A$ for some $A ∈\mathscr A$}

And intersection is

$∩A_{A∈ \mathscr A} = $ {$ x: x ∈ A$ for every $A ∈ \mathscr A$}

Now where I get confused is that I understand how to find the union of two sets A and B but I have a hard time figuring it out when it is just one set.

How does one find the union I think it is

$∪A$ = $(0, ∞ )$ since a natural number cannot be negative and

$∩A$ = ∅

This is my conjecture, any advice if I am going down the right path?

Comment: Both your answers look wrong to me. As $n$ increases the lefthand endpoint decreases from $\frac{1}{3}$ to 0 (but never reaches 0). The righthand endpoint decreases from $2\frac{1}{3}$ to 2 (but never reaches 2). So the union is $(0,2\frac{1}{3}]$ and the intersection is $[\frac{1}{3},2]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As to the union, if $A_n = [\frac{1}{n}, 2+\frac{1}{n}]$, where $n \ge 3$:

The left hand sides decrease down to $0$, never reaching it. So if we have any $x > 0$ and $x \le 1$, we can always find $n_0$ such that $0 < \frac{1}{n_0} < x$, as $\frac{1}{n}$ decreases down to $0$. So this $x$ is in $A_{n_0}$, and so is in the union of the $A_n$. All points up from $1$ to $2 \frac{1}{3}$ are in $A_3$ and on the right hand side we will never add new points: no point larger than $2\frac{1}{3}$ can be in any $A_n$.

So $\cup_n A_n = (0,2\frac{1}{3}]$.

As to the intersection, the opposite is going on: we always have all points in $[\frac{1}{3}, 2]$, as $\frac{1}{n} \le \frac{1}{3}$ for $n \ge 3$ and $2 \le 2 + \frac{1}{n}$ for all $n$.

But if $x < \frac{1}{3}$ it is not in $A_3$, so cannot be in the intersection, and if $x > 2$, for some $n$ we have $2 + \frac{1}{n} < x$, and $x \notin A_n$ for such $n$, so also not in the intersection.

So $\cap_n A_n = [\frac{1}{3},2]$.

Comment: For the intersection eventually 1/x= 0 so that means that they will all share 2. For the union all the shared numbers from 0 to 7/3 because 0 is the smallest 7/3 will be the largest.

Comment: This graph helped me understand. This is correct right?https://www.desmos.com/calculator/9jasmopreo